# how to access multiple parameter from url in django?

Tags: django, django-views

this is my get url. I want to access all parameters like test,AAAAA,BBBBB,CCCCC
please help me.

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/test/?text=sample&AAAAA=on&BBBBB=on&CCCCC=on
```

I am accessing values like this

```
def test(request):
    # get the text
    get_text = request.GET.get('text', 'default')
    aaaaa = request.GET.get('AAAAA', 'default')
    bbbbb = request.GET.get('BBBBB', 'default')
    ccccc = request.GET.get('CCCCC', 'default')
```

Comment: What code have you tried?

Comment: I tried like this
aaaaa = request.GET.get('AAAAA', 'default')
bbbbb = request.GET.get('BBBBB', 'default')
it will gives value of only first parameter.

Comment: please include the code you tried.

Comment: just edited question with added code

Comment: What does your `urlpatterns` for this view look like?

Comment: I mention the url which I get
http://127.0.0.1:8000/test/?text=sample&AAAAA=on&BBBBB=on&CCCCC=on

Comment: Yeah, but the mistake you made is probably in the `urlpatterns`.  I need to know what you have there to confirm this.

Answer (score 0):

```
def test(request):
    keys_to_get = ['AAAAA', 'BBBBB', 'CCCCC']
    aaaaa, bbbbb, ccccc = [request.GET.get(key, 'default') for key in keys_to_get]
```